Calling a rest api from web application in docker compose, but getting nginx 502 Bad Gateway error
`The rest api is colocated along with web application container and nginx container in docker desktop
Below are the nginx configurations used
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port, proxy_connect_timeout 300, proxy_send_timeout 300,
proxy_read_timeout 300, send_timeout 300
The rest api should be called , and proceed , instead of the 502 Bad Gateway error`

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
